# What are the basics of vi editor?

Tags: unix

I want to know the basics of vi editor because I am new to linux  and currently I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: start with vimtutor

Comment: There are a lot of resources: [vimtutor](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/vimtutor1.html), [vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/), [pratical vim](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim/practical-vim), [mastering vim](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/110000687.do), [learning vi and vim](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529833.do), [instantly better vim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aHm36-na4-4)... But SE sites are not meant for listing and I think your question is too broad, instead you should try to search [/r/vim](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/) and maybe ask your question there.

Answer (score 1):

- `<esc>:q!` To close the file without saving.
- `<esc>:wq` To close the file with saving.

Those are the **first two commands** that I teach people who need to use VIM in a pinch. They are useful, and provide a base for understanding the use of the `<esc>` key and `:` commands.

As Christian mentioned in his comment, [VimTutor](https://superuser.com/questions/246487/how-to-use-vimtutor) is probably the best way to learn VIM. Just type `vimtutor` at the CLI and follow the instructions on the screen.